# Using Paint Bucket In Photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop

So i'm trying to use the paint bucket in Photoshop CS6 to design a logo for a client of mine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et7OO.png ( What I currently have)

I want to colour the pale bits left with a different shade of green, when I use the paint bucket it covers the whole image, how do I colour in the remaining bits with the colour I want?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to programming at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when picking the paint bucket you can change the tolerance in the top bar so that it only changes the colours you want. At the moment its most likely at 100 but if you change it to 20 or so it should work for you.

Another possibility could be that you are using the paint bucket on the wrong layer. Make sure you have the layer of piece of the image you want to change selected.

EDIT: Also, you are better off asking this question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). That community can help you better with that type of question.

Comment: Thanks man, changed the tolerance down to 10 and it worked fine. Will bear the other site in mind for next time.